# A question about 4 concyclic points

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

In a triangle $ABC$, let $I$ denote its incenter.  Points $D, E, F$ are chosen on the segments $BC, CA, AB$, respectively, such that $BD + BF = AC$ and $CD + CE = AB$.  The circumcircles of triangles $AEF, BFD, CDE$ intersect lines $AI, BI, CI$, respectively, at points $K, L, M$ (different from $A, B, C$), respectively.  Prove that $K, L, M, I$ are concyclic.

Can someone help me? This was part of the Indian IMO TST in 2013. No one solved it as far as I know. A solution would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my GeoGebra sketch is correct, then the four points $K$, $L$, $M$ (and thus also the circle containing them and $I$) are independent of the points $D$, $E$, $F$. Moreover, it appears that the three circumcircles meet at a common point that is *also* concyclic with $I$, $K$, $L$, $M$. Interesting.

Comment: Well thanks for commenting, it should be interesting because it is from the IMO selection test. :)

Comment: Progress: One can show that $K$ is the point on the angle bisector of $A$ such that $$|AK| = \frac{|BC|}{2\cos(A/2)}$$ That is, the feet of perpendiculars to $AB$ and $AC$ are each at distance $|BC|/2$ from $A$. Therefore, at least one of my earlier claims is true: $K$, $L$, $M$ are independent of $D$, $E$, $F$.

Comment: Key Fact: The center of $\bigcirc IKLM$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @Blue have you solved it? You seem to make a lot of nice observations, Thank you. But I haven't been able to prove any of your observations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**Proof**.
Three circumcircles of $\triangle AFE$,$\triangle BDF$,$\triangle CED$ concur at $M$ (**Miquel** point)
$\angle BB'M+\angle AA'M=\angle BFM+\angle AFM=180^{\circ}$ and then $\square IA'MB'$ is concyclic.
Likewise, $\square IB'MC'$ is concyclic and then $I$,$A'$,$B'$,$C'$,$M$ are concyclic.

**Remark**.
(1) $I$ need not be incenter.
(2) $BF+BD=AC$, $CD+CE=AB$ are useless.

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma.** Given $\overline{XP} \cong \overline{XQ}$ and $\overline{XY}\cong\overline{ZQ}$ (and $\overline{XZ} \cong\overline{YP}$) as in the diagram, let $K$ be isosceles $\triangle XPQ$'s circumcenter (which necessarily lies on the bisector of $\angle X$). Then $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $K$ are concyclic.

[image]

**Proof of Lemma.** Evidently, $\triangle XYK \cong \triangle QZK$ (and $\triangle XZK \cong \triangle PYK$). Thus, $\angle XYK$ and $\angle XZK$ are supplementary, so that $\square XYKZ$ is cyclic. $\square$

Note that the Lemma implies that perpendiculars from $K$ meet $\overline{XP}$ and $\overline{XQ}$ at midpoints $M$ and $N$.

[image]

Thus,

> $$|\overline{XM}| = |\overline{XN}| = \frac{1}{2}\left(\;|\overline{XY}| + |\overline{XZ}|\;\right)\quad\quad(\star)$$

---

In the problem at hand, we observe that the relations
$|\overline{BD}|+|\overline{BE}| = b$ and $|\overline{CE}| + |\overline{CD}| = c$ imply the counterpart $|\overline{AE}| + |\overline{AF}| = a$, which, by $(\star)$, tells us (for instance) that a perpendicular from $K$ meets $\overline{AC}$ at $K^\prime$ such that $|\overline{AK^\prime}| = a/2$. The location of $K^\prime$ (and $K$) is *independent* of the positions of $D$, $E$, $F$.

[image]

Writing $H$ for the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$, and $H^\prime$ for the foot of the perpendicular from $H$ to $\overline{AB}$, we have $|\overline{BH^\prime}| = c/2$. From here, one can show that 
$$|\overline{HK}|^2 = R(R-2r) = |\overline{HI}|^2 \qquad (\star\star)$$
where $R$ and $r$ are, respectively, the circumradius and inradius of $\triangle ABC$, and where the second equality is [Euler's Triangle Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry). Since $|\overline{HI}|$ is symmetric in the triangle's elements, we can replace $K$ with $L$ and $M$ in $(\star)$, so that:
$$|\overline{HI}| = |\overline{HK}| = |\overline{HL}| = |\overline{HM}|$$
showing that $I$, $K$, $L$, $M$ lie on a circle with center $H$.

---

My derivation of the first equality in $(\star\star)$ involves tedious and complicated trig. I'm still seeking an elegant solution.

Comment: I have a question for you, if you could help me a bit. You say "which, by $(*)$ tells us a perpendicular from $K$ meets $AC$ at $K^{\prime}$ and $|\overline{AK^{\prime}}|=a/2$" but how do you conclude this from $(*)$? and how do you say the position of $K$ and $K^{\prime}$ are independent of $D,E,F$? Also if you could please put your proof of the fact $|\overline{HK}|^2=R(R-2r)$, it would be very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $(\star)$ says that the point $K$, on the bisector of $\angle X$ is concyclic with $\triangle XYZ$ when the perpendicular from $K$ meets the side of the angle at a point ($K^\prime$) whose distance from the vertex is half the total distance $|XY|+|XZ|$. In the problem, $|AE|+|AF|$ is $a$ (that is, |BC|), so that the distance from $K^\prime$ to vertex $A$ is half that: $a/2$. The exact locations of $D$, $E$, $F$ don't matter, because the locations of $K$, $L$, $M$ depend only on the sums-of-distances $|AE|+|AF|$, $|BD|+|BF|$, and $|CD|+|CE|$, which are simply $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: As I mentioned, my current proof of $(\star\star)$ is tedious and complicated. I'd rather not type-up the whole thing as it stands, but here are some relevant facts:
$$|HK|^2=|H^\prime K^\prime|^2 + (|HH^\prime|−|KK^\prime|)^2$$
$$|H^\prime K^\prime|=\frac{1}{2}|c−a|\qquad|KK^\prime|=\frac{a/2}{\tan(A/2)}\qquad |HH^\prime|=R^2−(c/2)^2$$
And by the Law of Sines,
$$a=2 R \sin A \qquad b = 2 R \sin B \qquad c = 2 R \sin C$$

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation, now its all clear, actually as proved in the lemma, I was trying to look for the isosceles triangle, but that was not necessary actually. Very elegant proof I have to agree. Thanks for helping.